# Calling a lambda expression multiple times

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying the lambda-expressions from the new standard, and still don't understand them quite well.

Let's say I have a lambda somewhere in my code, e.g. in my main:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //some code
    [](int x, int y)->float
    {
        return static_cast<float>(x) / static_cast<float>(y);
    };
    //some more code here
    //<---now I want to use my lambda-expression here
}
```

Well obviously I might need to use it multiple times, so the answer "just define it right there" doesn't work :P So, how do I call this lambda expression later in the code? Do I have to make a function pointer to it and use that pointer? Or is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can store the lambda using `auto`, or assign it to a compatible `std::function` explicitly:

```
auto f1 = [](int x, int y)->float{ ..... };
std::function<float(int,int)> f2 = [](int x, int y)->float{ ..... };

float x = f1(3,4);
auto y = f2(5,6);
```

You can always use `f1` or `f2` to construct or assign to a specific `std::function` type later on if necessary:

```
std::function<float(int,int)> f3 = f1;
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be implying (perhaps not intentionally), that the second form (using `auto`) is just a shorthand for the first form (using `std::function`).  It should be clarified that they are not the same, and the second form is better not simply because it's less verbose, but because it doesn't come with the (in this case) unnecessary overhead that `std::function` brings due to type erasure.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley actually the implication was intentional, although I realize it might be erroneous. I thought `auto` had to resolve to a type, and I thought in this case it would be an `std::function`. If you could shed some light on this I will fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh, right then.  It is of course true that auto resolves to a type.  But in this case, that type is unnameable.  The compiler will have a name it uses internally for it, which you might see if you use the lambda erroneously.  GCC, for example, will give it a name like `main()::<lambda(int,int)>` if the lambda is declared in main.  The major difference is that the `std::function` is a variable which can hold any function, function object, or lambda with the appropriate signature.  Whereas the lambda variable can only hold one type, the lambda itself.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley OK, I somehow confused myself about the issue. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 17):

```
auto lambda = [](int x, int y)->float
    {
        return static_cast<float>(x) / static_cast<float>(y);
    };
// code
// call lambda
std::cout << lambda(1, 2) << std::endl;
```