# Call the same lambda several times in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

Can lambda be reused?
I'd like to call this lambda a few times. But I can't find a way to give it a name.

```
[]() { cout << "lambda is called"; };
```

And what is the purpose of lambda without invoking like this? Compiler does not yell at the code above, but it is useless. Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a lambda expression multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049415/calling-a-lambda-expression-multiple-times)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can give it a name using the `auto` specifier:

```
auto f = []() { cout << "lambda is called"; };
```

That will allow you to invoke it with `f()`. But bear in mind that the type of a lambda isn't specified, so if you want to pass it to functions, you'll need to use templates (or convert to `std::function<void()>`).

```
template <typename F>
void three_times(F g) {
    g(); g(); g();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to reuse a lambda you need to assign it to a variable.

```
auto lambda = []() { cout << "lambda is called"; };
```

gives you an object named `lambda` that you can call the `operator ()` on to execute the body of the lambda like

```
lambda();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes lamda can be reused. See the example below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename F> void func2(F f) {
  f("func2");
}
void func(function<void(const char *)> f) {
  f("func");
}
int main() {
  auto l = [](const char *s) {
             cout << s << "\n";
           };
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    l("main"); // Calling lambda multiple times
    func(l);   // Passing lambda to a function using function<>
    func2(l);  // Passing lambda to a function using template
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
main
func
func2
main
func
func2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily give a lambda a name by assigning it to an `auto` variable - like so;

```
const auto l = [] { whatever };
```

Then call `l` multiple times as `l();` .

Answer (score 3):

Store the lambda using auto
or assign it to a compatible std::function explicitly:

```
auto f1 = [](int x, int y)->float{ ..... };
std::function<float(int,int)> f2 = [](int x, int y)->float{ ..... };
float x = f1(3,4);
auto y = f2(5,6);
std::function<float(int,int)> f3 = f1;
```

Comment: lambdas are not `std::function`s and `std::function` comes with some overhead, just saying